# Entity Framework Core CosmosDB upsert (update/insert) recognition

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have a [package](https://github.com/freer4/ef-vue-mantle) I built a while back that works with EF-created SQL databases just great. I've recently had a call to try to use with CosmosDB and guid "primary keys". My first foray into Cosmos.

When saving records I'm checking the value of the primary key: if it's the default value for the type, I consider it an insert; if it's not, then I consider it an update.

```
public virtual TModel Save(TModel data)
    {
        _dynamic.Add(data);
        _context.Entry(data).State =
            data.Id.Equals(default(TKey))
                ? EntityState.Added 
                : EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return data;
    }
```

I vaguely recall doing this for a performance reason, so I'm not pulling the records down from the database before updating them. It doesn't appear that there's a built-in upsert?

I believe the `Id` property is populated here on inserts for CosmosDB because CosmosDB doesn't generate its own Ids and instead relies on EF to provide it. Which is sensible, but breaks my convention here.

I suppose the ultimate question is, is there a better way to handle "upserts" here that doesn't rely on the `Id` being not-set?

**More Info**
The `TModel data` passed in is from a user request, at this point we:

1. Haven't pulled anything down from the database
2. Don't have any other records with pending changes in the context
3. There's another, nearly identical function that adds a range of data then calls `SaveChanges` so we are being somewhat diligent about work load here

The reason for doing the upsert pattern here is that the user has a single API endpoint that data gets saved to, whether it's a new record or an existing one.

We are essentially circumventing the DB upsert performance issues by telling it "this is an update" or "this is an insert" with this method, it's simply broken down because the `Id` for an inserted record is generated at this point for CosmosDB, where that wasn't an issue with the SQL version.

It looks as though I may just need to dig deeper into the CosmosDB internals and their EF interactions.

Comment: There's no need for this `Save` at all, in fact it's a serious bug for many reasons. 1) `DbContext.Update` attaches an entity in the Added or Modified state based on the PK already. 2) `SaveChanges` persists *all* pending changes. That single `Save` can actually perform 42 DELETEs and 67 INSERTs. 3) A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work already, and `SaveChanges` actually commits all changes. Replace `Save` with `Update` and only call `SaveChanges` at the very end of an operation, to commit all pending changes. If you want to discard changes, just don't call `SaveChanges` and dispose DbContext

Comment: As for a better solution, it depends on what you mean "better" and *why* you want a better solution. Most options actually perform worse, unless you have a *very* specific problem. Checking if an object exists requires 1 extra SQL query. Using MERGE or MySQL's INSERT ON DUPLICATE is actually pretty bad, resulting in bad execution plans and bad performance, because it converts an INSERT into an UPDATE in the middle of a query's *execution*. When you persist multiple objects this can become even worse. If you have *lots*, eg 1000s of objects, you're doing ETL and ORMs cause more harm than good

Comment: In *your specific case* though, Cosmos DB is a document database with a SQL facade (among others), not a relational database. There's an [UpsertItemAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.upsertitemasync?view=azure-dotnet) but no `UpdateItem`. [CreateItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/quickstart-dotnet?tabs=azure-portal%2Cwindows%2Cpasswordless%2Csign-in-azure-cli#create-an-item) itself upserts. What you ask is probably how EF Core already works with CosmosDB.

Comment: As for the key itself, it's not a GUID, it's a *string*. As long as you use a unique string, you can use anything you want. For example, it can be an invoice number. This way, there's no real reason for an auto-generated key. The key isn't really used for FK constraints because a *document* represents an entire graph of objects (invoice, line items, details etc), not a single row.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added more info. Maybe this pattern is overkill, but I must have had a reason for doing it originally. I'm getting old, the skull sponge is a bit dry.

Comment: Maybe you can check the `Id` before to add the entity in the tracker?

Comment: @vernou that is the strategy I'm working on now, but I'm also taking the time to learn more of the inner mechanics to ensure I'm not overcomplicating something like Panagiotis pointed out

Answer (score 1):

**Entity Framework Core CosmosDB upsert (update/insert) recognition:**

> Below is a better way to handle "upserts" here that doesn't rely on the `Id` being not-set

**Explanation:**

- A new data record of type **TModel** is created inside the `try` block, and an **upsert** operation is carried out using the repository.
- An **upsert** operation either creates a new document if it doesn't exist or updates an existing document.
- A query is defined in the **upsert** method to determine whether any existing data with the specified Role exists.
- A query iterator is used to perform the query, and the first result is obtained `using.FirstOrDefault()`.
- If no existing data is found, a new "id" is generated for the document in case there is no existing data with the specified "Role" property else it updates the existing data.

```cs
var client = new CosmosClient(cosmosEndpoint, cosmosKey);
var cosmosContainer = client.GetContainer("upsertDb", "upsertCont");

var repository = new YourRepository(cosmosContainer);
try
 {
    var newData = new TModel
     {
       Role = "FullStackDeveloper",
       Name = "Balaji"
     };
Console.WriteLine($"Role: {newData.Role}");
await repository.Upsert(newData);

Console.WriteLine("Upsert operation completed successfully.");
 }
catch (CosmosException ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"CosmosException: {ex.Message}");
   Console.WriteLine($"Status Code: {ex.StatusCode}");
 }
catch (Exception ex)
 {
   Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected error occurred: {ex.Message}");
 }

public class YourRepository
{
  private readonly Container _container;
  public YourRepository(Container container)
  {
     _container = container;
  }
  public async Task Upsert(TModel data)
   {
     var partitionKey = new PartitionKey(data.Role);
     try
     {
       var query = new QueryDefinition($"SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Role = @role").WithParameter("@role", data.Role);
       var queryIterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<TModel>(query);
       var existingData = (await queryIterator.ReadNextAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

       if (existingData == null)
       {
          data.id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
          await _container.CreateItemAsync(data, partitionKey);
       }
       else
       {
          data.id = existingData.id; // Set the existing 'id' before upserting
          await _container.UpsertItemAsync(data, partitionKey);
       }
     }
     catch (CosmosException ex)
     {
       throw;
     }
   }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

[image]